# How to do the horizontal alignment of HTML components

Tags: html, css

Have a look on [target code](https://jsfiddle.net/arjunsreepad/hnmgnLat/).Here I am trying to split the main div into 2 equal halves and place the 2 tables at center of each of them.
Please help me to do the same

```
<div id="title">
Split Screen into 2 equaly halves
</div>
<div >
<table id="myTable">
<tr >
    <td ></td>
    <td class="row_bottom"></td>
    <td ></td>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td class="row_top"></td>
    <td class="row"></td>
    <td class="row_top"></td>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td ></td>
    <td class="row_bottom"></td>
    <td ></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id="myTable">
<tr >
    <td ></td>
    <td class="row_bottom"></td>
    <td ></td>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td class="row_top"></td>
    <td class="row"></td>
    <td class="row_top"></td>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td ></td>
    <td class="row_bottom"></td>
    <td ></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arjunsreepad/hnmgnLat/%60 is not work

Comment: can you give the CODE you tryed already??

Comment: nobody see that he used the id="myTable" two times in his code http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as splitting one element into two halves. Instead make 2 elements and position them properly.

Make divs 50% of the width of the parent element (body in this case). Make them float to the left.

Align the tables inside using

```
margin: 50px auto;
```

Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/hnmgnLat/2/

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

add this style in css

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.child {
  min-width:50%;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an ID only one TIME in your CODE  and then you do an left and right float

or you can use flexbox

```css
.row
{
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.row_top
{
 
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top:2px solid black;
  border-bottom:2px solid black; 

}
.row_bottom
{
 
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-left:2px solid black;
  border-right:2px solid black;


}
.test{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#title
{

 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 width: 250px;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
 Split Screen into 2 equaly halves
</div>
<div class="test">
 
  <table id="myTableleft">
 <tr >
  <td ></td>
  <td class="row_bottom"></td>
  <td ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr >
  <td class="row_top"></td>
  <td class="row"></td>
  <td class="row_top"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr >
  <td ></td>
  <td class="row_bottom"></td>
  <td ></td>
 </tr>
</table>
 
  <table id="myTableright">
 <tr >
  <td ></td>
  <td class="row_bottom"></td>
  <td ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr >
  <td class="row_top"></td>
  <td class="row"></td>
  <td class="row_top"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr >
  <td ></td>
  <td class="row_bottom"></td>
  <td ></td>
 </tr>
</table>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the two tables in different divs.set the width of the two divs to 45% each. Then set the float of the first div to left. I hope this works. The 45% width should give room for margin and padding in case it exist. Or better still set all padding and margin to 0px and set the width to 50%